# How to test a web service with up to 1 million users?

Tags: performance-testing, scalability, load-testing

I'd like to know how to test a web service with up to 1 million active users, all accessing the site at the same time.

This is in theory - I don't have a web service like this, but was recently [reading this article on how to build a scalable app for > 500K users](https://medium.com/unboxd/how-i-built-an-app-with-500-000-users-in-5-days-on-a-100-server-77deeb238e83#.nm2yp8cz9), and it got me wondering how people would test this?

For the sake of discussion, lets assume that I'm in full control of the service and have 1 million test accounts already created, with the usernames `test1` -> `test1000000` available. I'd prefer that the accounts were accessing my service from places all over the world, but am open to any suggestions!

EDIT: I'm familiar with JMeter and Selenium, but was concerned with the idea that possibly the client activity if all run from a single location would be bottlenecked by the local network, and thus not a great test? So instead of having say 10 JMeter clients at different locations running 100K clients, I was thinking that it might be better to have 1000 JMeter clients testing 1000 users each, all from different locations... but maybe this isn't much of a concern?

Comment: http://locust.io/
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think at a high level, there could be test nodes distributed around the world.  Each would contain the logic to authenticate and execute a certain type of transaction.  Blocks of test accounts could be distributed to each node and each node would launch the tests in parallel.

At a practical level I would start by looking at a framework locust.io claims it does this in its tag line :)

http://locust.io/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [apache jmeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) or my personal preference [siege](https://github.com/JoeDog/siege)

In case of siege I would think of generating a urls.txt file with million urls each representing a call from a user and running them concurrently.

As for your concern about the locations 
[Blazemeter](http://blazemeter.com/) has a geo-distributed stress testing too

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look on Tsung tool http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/
It is really light weight and allows to run hundred of thousand virtual users from average machine (depends from your script difficulty).

Answer (score 0):

While you can't do multi step automation at these sites, the following services will let you hit an url from different client locations (e.g Asia, North America, Australia), and throttle the bandwidth if you like for testing purposes:

***WebPageTest*** - https://www.webpagetest.org/
- from their about page: "WebPagetest is an open source project that is primarily being developed and supported by Google as part of our efforts to make the web faster." This site also has an api, is opensource, and allows you to automate it via a node api and cli.

Pingdom
https://tools.pingdom.com/

More info in [this blogpost from KeyCDN](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/cdn-performance/)